# problem to display date format with rails 3.0 ajax using js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi 
In my application I append a date received from the user **in a dd/mm/yyyy format** for example("11/11/2010") to a selection list using ajax and js.erb file

my selection list code is

```
<select name="hour[reported_date]" id="customDate_link_hours">
    <option value="Today">Today</option>
    <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="Custom_range">Select Date</option>
</select>
```

in the controller I assign the date which is received from the user to a @display_date variable

```
@display_date=params[:hour][:reported_date]
```

in the js.erb file i do

```
$('#customDate_link_hours').append($('<option></option>').attr('value',<%=@display_date%>).attr('selected',true).text(<%=@display_date%>))
```

the function is working ok but i getting **very strange final input**
for example, if i add the date "18/11/2010" the received appended value to the select list  is **"0.013888888888"** 
if i get the date "2/11/201" the received appended value to the select list  is "0.00009045687471733". 
 
I suspect that the problem is in the "/" character of the date format because when i tried to enter some other strings like "18112010" every thing was working ok
I will mostly appreciate if someone could  tell me what to do in order to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around your ERB block:

```
$('#customDate_link_hours')
    .append($('<option></option>')
    .attr('value','<%=@display_date%>')
    .attr('selected',true).text('<%=@display_date%>'));
```

Right now Javascript is seeing a literal 2/11/201 and treating it as a division.